# Override Twitter Meteor package whitelist fields

Tags: twitter, meteor

Is it possible to change the whitelist for Twitter auth without overriding the entire meteor package?

Basically I want to change this:

Twitter.whitelistedFields = ['profile_image_url', 'profile_image_url_https', 'lang'];

to something like this:

Twitter.whitelistedFields = ['profile_image_url', 'profile_image_url_https', 'lang', 'name', 'id_str', 'url', 'description', 'location'];

Comment: Which meteor twitter package are you refering to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the whitelist is exposed on the exported object you could create a wrapper package:

```
//Package.js
api.use('twitter')
api.imply('twitter')

api.add_files('wrapper.js')

//Wrapper.js
Twitter.whitelistedFields = ['profile_image_url', 'profile_image_url_https', 'lang', 'name', 'id_str', 'url', 'description', 'location']
```

If you're talking about the built in accounts twitter package you could specify the requestPermissions option: http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_loginwithexternalservice, I don't know exactly what the format for that is for twitter, but I've successfully used this method to download profile info from github.

**Update**

@GeorgeD. pointed out that the `requestPermissions` option is not available for Twitter, Weibo, or Meteor developer accounts.

Comment: Twitter, Weibo, Meteor developer accounts: requestPermissions currently not supported